Python formatting float to n signficaint digits
I would like to convert a set of floats to strings with 3 significant digits, e.g.
10.00 --> 10.0 
10.10 --> 10.1 
101.10 --> 101 

Using "{:.3g}".format(x) results in 10, 10.1, 101 which is not what I want as I would like 10.0 instead of 10. Using "{:#.3g}".format(x) results in 10.0, 10.1, 101. which adds an extra dot at the end of 101
I am using python 3.9.
I have tried using g and f formats and have not found a simple solution.

How about "{:#.3g}".format(x).rstrip(".")?

That works if there is only a single float in that string, but I'm creating a long string with many of these floats to populate a latex table so I was hoping to find a compact way. In the end, I ended up doing something similar to your suggestion
